# Proof of derived tensor-hom adjunction

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, derived-functors, derived-categories, hom-functor

**EDIT:** this has now been cross-posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401580/proof-of-derived-tensor-hom-adjunction).

As far as I know, for $R,S,V,W$ rings and $M$ an $(R,W)$-bimodule, $N$ an $(R,S)$-bimodule and $L$ an $(S,V)$-bimodule, we have an isomorphism in D($V$-lmod)
$$
\text{RHom}_R(N \otimes_S^L L, M) \cong \text{RHom}_S(L,\text{RHom}_R(N,M)).
$$

The only proof I can imagine would take flat / injective resolutions $P^\bullet$ and $Q^\bullet$ of $N$ and $M$ to yield
$$
\text{Hom}^\bullet_R(P^\bullet \otimes_S L, Q^\bullet) \cong \text{Hom}^\bullet_S(L,\text{Hom}^\bullet_R(P^\bullet,Q^\bullet)).
$$
However, it is not clear to me why there exists a resolution of $N$ consisting of $(R,S)$-bimodules that are flat right-$S$-modules.
For instance let $S=\mathbb Z$, $R = \mathbb Z/p$, in which case all flat $S$-modules are torsion free, so none of them can have an $R$-module structure.

Does the 'derived adjunction' still hold? If yes, how do you prove it?